# How to change size size of mel-spectograms?

Tags: python, matplotlib, audio, librosa

I want to save 3 mel-spectograms to one png file. I used the subplots function for this.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1)
img1 = librosa.display.specshow(S_dB1, sr=sr, fmax=10000, ax=ax[0])
img2 = librosa.display.specshow(S_dB2, sr=sr, fmax=10000, ax=ax[1])
img3 = librosa.display.specshow(S_dB3, sr=sr, fmax=10000, ax=ax[2])
fig.savefig('img.png')
```

This is what the generated mel-spectrograms look like.

[image]

Any option to change the height of these mel-spectograms to make them easier to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To control the aspect ratio of the figure, use fig size. It is (width,height) in inches.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1, figsize=(16,16))
```